# Why Python loops over slices of numpy arrays are faster than fully vectorized operations

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a boolean mask by thresholding a 3D data array: mask at locations where data are smaller than lower acceptable limit or data are larger than upper acceptable limit must be set to `True` (otherwise `False`). Succinctly:

```
mask = (data < low) or (data > high)
```

I have two versions of the code for performing this operation: one works directly with entire 3D arrays in `numpy` while the other method loops over slices of the array. Contrary to my expectations, the second method seems to be faster than the first one. Why???

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: print(sys.version)
3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

In [4]: print(np.__version__)
1.14.0

In [5]: arr = np.random.random((10, 1000, 1000))

In [6]: def method1(arr, low, high):
   ...:     """ Fully vectorized computations """
   ...:     out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
   ...:     np.greater_equal(arr, high, out)
   ...:     np.logical_or(out, arr < low, out)
   ...:     return out
   ...: 

In [7]: def method2(arr, low, high):
   ...:     """ Partially vectorized computations """
   ...:     out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
   ...:     for k in range(arr.shape[0]):
   ...:         a = arr[k]
   ...:         o = out[k]
   ...:         np.greater_equal(a, high, o)
   ...:         np.logical_or(o, a < low, o)
   ...:     return out
   ...:
```

First of all, let's make sure that both methods produce identical results:

```
In [8]: np.all(method1(arr, 0.2, 0.8) == method2(arr, 0.2, 0.8))
Out[8]: True
```

And now some timing tests:

```
In [9]: %timeit method1(arr, 0.2, 0.8)
14.4 ms ± 111 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit method2(arr, 0.2, 0.8)
11.5 ms ± 241 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

What is going on here?

---

**EDIT 1:** A similar behavior is observed in an older environment:

```
In [3]: print(sys.version)
2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

In [4]: print(np.__version__)
1.11.3

In [9]: %timeit method1(arr, 0.2, 0.8)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit method2(arr, 0.2, 0.8)
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop
```

Comment: This might be an effect of better cache efficiency.  The first version can't make good use of the processor's cache, since the array doesn't fit in.  By dividing it in ten parts, you can perform all operations on parts fitting into the cache before moving on to the next part.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I was thinking that too, but continue observing similar performance differences after increasing second and third dimensions of arr's shape to 5K and 10K instead of 1K and 1K. Wouldn't that cause the ''smaller'' chunks in method2 to also no longer fit in cache?

Comment: @DennisSoemers Yeah, I was already doubting my own comment after noticing that each of the ten chunks would be 8MB in size, which is right at the limit of the biggest typcial L3 caches.  If it's not caching, I have no idea – I guess the OP will need to profile the compiled code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Caching is still an interesting idea so please leave your comment. Interestingly, decreasing third dimension to 100 results in equal timings and decreasing it down to 10 *finally* makes `method1()` faster than `method2()`.

Comment: A modest number of iterations (here 10) on a relatively complex task are often competitive with single step version.  My guess is that the memory management overhead for larger arrays starts balance out iteration overhead.  Where the trade off occurs may depend on processor, OS, and numpy internals.  I observed this in MATLAB years ago.  Others have commented on it with respect to `dot` products.

Comment: @hpaulj When you refer to "memory management" do you mean page faults or something else? Also, isn't "memory management" about the same in both methods since the arrays (`arr` and `out`) are the same and the difference is only in how data are accessed? For example in `method2()`, smaller "arrays" `a` and `o` are simply views into the same large array?

Comment: Your `numpy.sum` test is comparing inequivalent computations; `np.sum(arr, axis=0)` sums along axis 0, while `[np.sum(a) for a in arr]` sums along every axis but 0.

Comment: @user2357112 Yep, I was wrong about `sum()`. Deleting 2nd edit. Many thanks

Comment: On an older PC (core2 with linux), 1.14 numpy, `method2` is a bit slower.

Comment: @hpaulj Interesting... On my android phone `method2()` is a bit slower as well but both methods run about the same (within margin of error) if third dimension is decreased to 100 or 10.

Comment: I tried this comparison on an older PC (recycled desktop) with the same `numpy`, but with different OS builds (Ubuntu 16 32bit v 17 64bit).  On the 32 your `method2` was a bit slower.  on the 64, both were 2x faster, with `method2` a bit faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, essentially, this essentially confirms what you said before about architecture dependence. Still a weird result *on my machine* that was just bothering me. I'll just choose `method1` as it is standard and what I would expect to work better. I was curious if there exist any logical explanation for this and hopefully to learn something out of this...

Comment: Is using Numba not an option for you? On my PC (Core i7-4771) a simple jit compiled function outperforms method_1 by a factor of two and method_1 by 50%. This will avoid both bad cache behaivior (method_1) and slow Python loops and function calls (method_2)

Answer (score 3):

**Outperforming both methods**

In method one you are accessing the array twice. If it doesn't fit in the cache, the data will be read two times from RAM which lowers the performance. Additionally it is possible that temporary arrays are created as mentioned in the comments.

Method two is more cache friendly, since you are accessing a smaller part of the array twice, which is likely to fit in cache. The downsides are slow looping and more function calls, which are also quite slow.

To get a good performance here it is recommended to compile the code, which can be done using cython or numba. Since the cython version is some more work (annotating, need of a seperate compiler), I will show how to do this using Numba.

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True, cache=True)
def method3(arr, low, high):
  out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=nb.boolean)
  for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
      for k in range(arr.shape[2]):
        out[i,j,k]=arr[i,j,k] < low or arr[i,j,k] > high
  return out
```

Using `arr = np.random.random((10, 1000, 1000))` this outperforms your method_1 by a factor of two and your method_2 by 50 percent on my PC (Core i7-4771, python 3.5, windows)

This is only a simple example, on more complex code, where you can make use of SIMD, and parallel processing which is also very easy to use the performance gain can be a lot bigger. On non compiled code vectorization is usualy but not always (as shown) the best you can do, but it will always lead to a bad cache behaiviour which can lead to suboptimal performance if the chunks of data you are acessing don't fit at least in L3 cache. On some other problems there will be also a performance hit if the data can't fit in the much smaller L1 or L2 cache. Another advantage will be automatic inlining of small njited functions in a njited function which calls this functions.

Comment: I can't use `numba` but it is an interesting approach anyway. It is not clear to me what do you mean by _"On non compiled code vectorization is usualy but not always (as shown) the best you can do..."_ Isn't `numpy` (mostly) compiled?

Comment: If you vectorize your code using numpy, you usually call a compiled function with multiple data (e.g) an array. If you do multiple operations on the same data (where caching is apropriate) this can be a bit slow because you have to read the data multiple times from RAM if it doesn't fit in cache. 
BTW: Why can't you use Numba (at least to compile standalone functions). It is often the easiest aproach to get performant code.

Answer (score 0):

In my own tests, the difference in performance was even more noticeable than in your question. The differences continued to be clearly observable after increasing second and third dimensions of the `arr` data. It also continued to be observable after commenting out one of the two comparison functions (`greater_equal` or `logical_or`), which means we can rule out some kind of strange interaction between the two.

By changing the implementation of the two methods to the following, I could significantly reduce the observable difference in performance (but not completely eliminate it):

```
def method1(arr, low, high):
    out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    high = np.ones_like(arr) * high
    low = np.ones_like(arr) * low
    np.greater_equal(arr, high, out)
    np.logical_or(out, arr < low, out)
    return out

def method2(arr, low, high):
    out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    high = np.ones_like(arr) * high
    low = np.ones_like(arr) * low
    for k in range(arr.shape[0]):
        a = arr[k]
        o = out[k]
        h = high[k]
        l = low[k]
        np.greater_equal(a, h, o)
        np.logical_or(o, a < l, o)
    return out
```

I suppose that, when supplying `high` or `low` as a scalar to those numpy functions, they may internally first create a numpy array of the correct shape filled with that scalar. When we do this manually outside the functions, in both cases only once for the full shape, the performance difference becomes much less noticeable. This implies that, for whatever reason (maybe cache?), creating such a large array filled with the same constant once may be less efficient than creating `k` smaller arrays with the same constant (as done automatically by the implementation of `method2` in the original question).

---

**Note:** in addition to reducing the performance gap, it also makes the performance of both methods much worse (affecting the second method more severly than the first). So, while this may give some indication of where the issue may be, it doesn't appear to explain everything.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a new version of `method2`, where we now manually pre-create smaller arrays within the loop every time, like I suspect is happening internally in numpy in the original implementation in the question:

```
def method2(arr, low, high):
    out = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    for k in range(arr.shape[0]):
        a = arr[k]
        o = out[k]
        h = np.full_like(a, high)
        l = np.full_like(a, low)
        np.greater_equal(a, h, o)
        np.logical_or(o, a < l, o)
    return out
```

This version is indeed much faster again than the one I have above (confirming that creating many smaller arrays inside the loop is more efficient than one big one outside the loop), but still slower than the original implementation in the question.

Under the hypothesis that these numpy functions are indeed converting the scalar bounds into these kinds of arrays first, the difference in performance between this last function and the one in the question could be due to creation of arrays in Python (my implementation) vs. doing so natively (original implementation)

Comment: I want to thank you looking into this issue! You say _"This implies that, for whatever reason (maybe cache?), creating such a large array filled with the same constant once may be less efficient than creating k smaller arrays with the same constant ..."_ I am not sure this is the case in *your* functions: in both methods you create one large array `np.ones_like(arr)`. In `method2()` you just create views into that array inside the loop - you do not *create* many smaller arrays. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AGNGazer no that's exactly correct. In my code, I tried to manually make it so that `method2` now has the same ''mistake'' that I suspect `method1` already had to begin with, in order to see if that removes the performance gap. This change does indeed make the performance levels be closer to each other for me, but also much worse for both (so `method1` originally wasn't THIS bad). There also still is a clear performance gap, just a smaller one

Comment: So I doubt this is the full story. Probably part of it though

Comment: _"I suppose that, when supplying high or low as a scalar to those numpy functions, they may internally first create a numpy array of the correct shape filled with that scalar."_ I am actually not very sure that `numpy` creates arrays internally: `%timeit np.less(arr, 0.2)` is `6.24 ms` while "pre-creating 0.2 *array*" `lim = 0.2 * np.ones_like(arr)` and then running comparison on this array gives: `%timeit np.less(arr, lim)` is `12.9 ms`. If in the first case `numpy` were creating internal arrays then I would have expected first timing to be no faster than second.

Comment: Creating those arrays internally could be faster due to it happening natively instead of partially in python. See new edit to my question, which does provide some more evidence for my hypothesis. I'm still definitely not 100% sure though, ideally would be able to check the numpy code but haven't been able to find anything readable

Comment: It is still not clear what is going on here... For smaller arrays that fit into cache, e.g., `(10,1000,10)`, I get the following timings: method1 - 61.1 µs, method2 - 88.4 µs, and your method2 (==method3): 25.6 µs. So, pre-creating arrays seems to speed up things and also makes you method fastest. Then I tried pre-creating constant arrays in method1 (I call it method1b) and it is much slower (cache problems???) With very large arrays (last dim=10000) I get method1b extremely slow 1.2s, method1 - 208ms, method2 - 178ms, method3 - 100ms.

Comment: That is, while you have found a way to speed things when working with small slices, for completely vectorized approach it (=pre-creating constant arrays) actually slows up computations. I doubt that this could be due to "internal creation" being much faster than explicit call. Something is just weird with staying completely within `numpy`.

Comment: Is the indentation of your method 2 `return out` line correct?

Comment: @DSM I guess not. However, I actually run this idea slightly differently: compute `high` and `low` appropriately as arrays outside `method?()` functions and pass them as arguments, i.e., `high = np.full_like(arr, 0.8)` for `method1()` and `high = np.full_like(arr[0], 0.8)` for `method2()`. The speed-up is dramatic using `method2()` (as well as the slowdown with `method1()`). - **EDIT:** Here `method1()` and `method2()` refer to the code in OP.

Comment: @DSM I take back everything I said above. Using `low` and `high` constant arrays instead of scalar values results in an almost 2x slowdown in the original `method2()`. Probably I was not careful and used the code from here as it was posted.

Comment: Your `method2`, with corrected `return` indent is significantly slower than the OP's on my machine.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah I know, that's exactly what I described in the text too. I didn't propose it as a faster alternative, I was trying to bring methods 1 and 2 closer together in performance (e.g. slowing down method2) in an attempt to figure out what implementation detail may explain the performance difference originally observed in question.