# Python Pandas - difference between 'loc' and 'where'?

Tags: python, pandas

Just curious on the behavior of 'where' and why you would use it over 'loc'.

If I create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
                   'Run Distance':[234,35,77,787,243,5435,775,123,355,123],
                   'Goals':[12,23,56,7,8,0,4,2,1,34],
                   'Gender':['m','m','m','f','f','m','f','m','f','m']})
```

And then apply the 'where' function:

```
df2 = df.where(df['Goals']>10)
```

I get the following which filters out the results where Goals > 10, but leaves everything else as NaN:

```
  Gender  Goals    ID  Run Distance                                                                                                                                                  
0      m   12.0   1.0         234.0                                                                                                                                                  
1      m   23.0   2.0          35.0                                                                                                                                                  
2      m   56.0   3.0          77.0                                                                                                                                                  
3    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
4    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
5    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
6    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
7    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
8    NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN                                                                                                                                                  
9      m   34.0  10.0         123.0
```

If however I use the 'loc' function:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Goals']>10]
```

It returns the dataframe subsetted without the NaN values:

```
  Gender  Goals  ID  Run Distance                                                                                                                                                    
0      m     12   1           234                                                                                                                                                    
1      m     23   2            35                                                                                                                                                    
2      m     56   3            77                                                                                                                                                    
9      m     34  10           123
```

So essentially I am curious why you would use 'where' over 'loc/iloc' and why it returns NaN values?

Comment: Related: [Pandas mask / where methods versus NumPy np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982417/pandas-mask-where-methods-versus-numpy-np-where). Summary: Pandas `where` rarely outperforms (or is more readable versus) the more popular NumPy `np.where`, so the former is often irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you jpp. Interesting question by you and response by 'ead'. I will look at numpy for using 'where'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Think of `loc` as a filter - give me only the parts of the df that conform to a condition.

`where` originally comes from numpy. It runs over an array and checks if each element fits a condition. So it gives you back the entire array, with a result or `NaN`. A nice feature of `where` is that you can also get back something different, e.g. `df2 = df.where(df['Goals']>10, other='0')`, to replace values that don't meet the condition with 0.

```
ID  Run Distance Goals Gender
0   1   234      12     m
1   2   35       23     m
2   3   77       56     m
3   0   0        0      0
4   0   0        0      0
5   0   0        0      0
6   0   0        0      0
7   0   0        0      0
8   0   0        0      0
9   10  123      34     m
```

Also, while `where` is only for conditional filtering, `loc` is the standard way of selecting in Pandas, along with `iloc`. `loc` uses row and column names, while `iloc` uses their index number. So with `loc` you could choose to return, say, `df.loc[0:1, ['Gender', 'Goals']]`:

```
    Gender  Goals
0   m   12
1   m   23
```

Comment: That is super helpful, thank you. So 'loc' filters, and 'where' is more for where you want to change values that do not fit the condition to something else. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If check docs [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) it replace rows by condition - default by `NAN`, but is possible specify value:

```
df2 = df.where(df['Goals']>10)
print (df2)
     ID  Run Distance  Goals Gender
0   1.0         234.0   12.0      m
1   2.0          35.0   23.0      m
2   3.0          77.0   56.0      m
3   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
4   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
5   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
6   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
7   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
8   NaN           NaN    NaN    NaN
9  10.0         123.0   34.0      m

df2 = df.where(df['Goals']>10, 100)
print (df2)
    ID  Run Distance  Goals Gender
0    1           234     12      m
1    2            35     23      m
2    3            77     56      m
3  100           100    100    100
4  100           100    100    100
5  100           100    100    100
6  100           100    100    100
7  100           100    100    100
8  100           100    100    100
9   10           123     34      m
```

Another syntax is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and is for filter rows - remove rows matched condition.

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Goals']>10]
#alternative
df2 = df[df['Goals']>10]

print (df2)
   ID  Run Distance  Goals Gender
0   1           234     12      m
1   2            35     23      m
2   3            77     56      m
9  10           123     34      m
```

If use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is possible also filter by rows by condition and columns by name(s):

```
s = df.loc[df['Goals']>10, 'ID']
print (s)
0     1
1     2
2     3
9    10
Name: ID, dtype: int64

df2 = df.loc[df['Goals']>10, ['ID','Gender']]
print (df2)
   ID Gender
0   1      m
1   2      m
2   3      m
9  10      m
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much. Also thanks for the tip on the alternative!

Answer (score 7):

- `loc` retrieves only the rows that matches the condition.
- `where` returns the whole dataframe, replacing the rows that don't match the condition (NaN by default).

Comment: Great, thank you. 'Where' is a lot more useful than originally thought!