# Query date range and product size from xlsx file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, where-clause

I'm using python 3.6 to do this. Below are just a few important columns that I'm interested to query out.

```
 Auto-Gen Index : Product Container : Ship Date :.......
    0           :   Large Box       : 2017-01-09:.......
    1           :   Large Box       : 2012-07-15:.......
    2           :   Small Box       : 2012-07-18:.......
    3           :   Large Box       : 2012-07-31:.......
```

I would like to query rows that indicate Large Box as their product container and the shipping date must be in the period of July in the year of 2012.

```
 file_name = r'''Sample-Superstore-Subset-Excel.xlsx'''
 df = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = my_sheet)
 lb = df.loc[df['Product Container'] == 'Large Box'] //Get large box
 july = lb[(lb['Ship Date'] > '2012-07-01') & (lb['Ship Date'] < '2012-07-31')]
```

I just wonder how to use query and where condition by python(pd.query())?

Comment: Note that Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`

Answer (score 1):

If your question is when to use `loc` vs `where`, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900717/python-pandas-difference-between-loc-and-where/54900803#54900803):

> Think of `loc` as a filter - give me only the parts of the df that
>   conform to a condition.
>
> `where` originally comes from numpy. It runs over an array and checks if
>   each element fits a condition. So it gives you back the entire array,
>   with a result or NaN. A nice feature of where is that you can also get
>   back something different, e.g. df2 = df.where(df['Goals']>10,
>   other='0'), to replace values that don't meet the condition with 0.

If you are asking when to use `query`, AFAIK there is no real reason to do besides performance. If you have a very large dataset, query is expected to be faster. More on high-level performance [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).